# Java Spring Boot FTPClient connection method from another class doesn´t work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am trying to make a extra class that would take care of connection and status of the user, but I am still getting some wierd error, that I don´t understand.

This is my ´FTPConnection class
I created private ftpClient using DI (I have @Bean annotation in main class) and I am trying to connect to the server using this method from another class

```
@Autowired
private FTPClient ftpClient;

public void connect() {
    try {
        ftpClient.connect("host");
        ftpClient.login("username", "password");

        int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();

        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftpClient.disconnect();
            System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this is the class with the RequestMapping methods

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        var connection = new FTPConnection();

        try {

            connection.connect();
            System.out.println(connection.isConnected());
            FTPClient ftpClient = connection.getFtpClient();

            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/usb");
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            [...]
```

And the error that I am getting is

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>   at com.tenpetr.FTPFileUploader.FTPConnection.connect(FTPConnection.java:16) ~[main/:na]
>   at com.tenpetr.FTPFileUploader.FileTransfer.uploadFile(FileTransfer.java:29) ~[main/:na]
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ...

Dou you have any idea, why I am stuck here? Thanks for your advices.

Comment: please post the contents of FtpConnection constructor

Comment: @KompiKompi This class doesn´t have a constructor

Comment: you mean it has an empty default one? ;)

Comment: @KompiKompi Exactly :D

Comment: could you please add the empty constructor to the code and put a breakpoint there so we could see whether the FtpClient is initialized? how does the ftpClient class ad constructor look like?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is (will update after having more data) that the FtpClient is not correctly initialized and thus the FtpConnection is not correctly initialized as well.

TO BE UPDATED

Comment: Well, after setting some breakpoints, it looks like FTPCLient is not inicialized, which is wierd, because I have Bean annotation in the main class and as far as I know, it should inject it into field with Autowired...

Comment: could you please share the main class? did you try annotating the FtpClient with @Component?

Answer (score 0):

Defining a bean with singleton scope means the container creates a single instance of that bean

edited:

```
@Bean
@Scope("singleton")
    public FTPClient  ftpClient(){
        return new FTPClient();
    }
```

This won't work if you're trying to autowire an interface

Comment: But I dont want to create new instance of the FTPClient everytime I want to reconnect for example. Thats why I had this DI logic.

Comment: This make no sense co me... Why are you creating `Bean  public FTPClient ftpClient ...`  when you are also calling new FTPClient() in connect method. This should be singleton object.

Comment: Edited once again for you

Comment: Doesnt work, wtill getting null when Autowiring it in the FTPConnection class

Comment: @PetrJelínek if you will add this to your FtpConnection class it should work,  it did for me when i had the same issue, so instead of autowired replace it with the code i have provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212299/discussion-between-letmethink-and-petr-jelinek).